# Cauchy-Schwarz inequality extension for Hilbert-Schmidt inner products

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

My professor wrote that from using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $(|x \cdot y| \leq \|x\|\|y\|)$, we can show that for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$\|A\vec{x}\| \leq (\|A\|)_{HS}\|\vec{x}\|$

where the $(\|A\|)_{HS}$ = $\sqrt{\langle A,A\rangle_{HS}}$

and $\langle A,A\rangle_{HS}$ = Tr($A^{T}*A$) = $\sum_{i} \langle A^{T}e_{i},Ae_{i}\rangle$

I'm not too sure how he made this conclusion and was wondering if someone could clarify

Comment: What's $\langle A,A\rangle$?

Comment: <A,A> HS is the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product, which is equal to what I edited into the question based on what was covered previously in the lecture

Comment: I'm not sure this is true for x outside the unit ball of $R^n$

Comment: Hint: Apply Cauchy Schwarz on $(e_i^T A)x$.